# How to write array of functions in arduino library?

Tags: programming, arduino-mega, c++, c

I've nine functions each of type void as follow:

```
void zero();
void one();
void two();
void three();
void four();
void five();
void six();
void seven();
void eight();
void nine();
```

I've put all these functions into an array pointer as follow (without any error):

```
typedef void (*num_func) ();
num_func functions[] = { zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine};
```

Now I'm writing an arduino library and wanting to achieve the same, but after hours of thinking I'm not able to achieve. Please help me how can I accomplish this in a library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mikael
Sorry Mikael, I'm not able to comment at your answer (because stackexchange demands me to have 50 points before I can comment). Here is the error I'm getting from your implementation. **storage class specified for 'functions'**

Comment: What is your setup? I do not get that error. Obviously there must be some implementation of the functions and there must be a sketch that uses the library.

Comment: Yup, I've the implementation of the functions in .cpp file (for all of these zero() etc. functions).

And also, I'm getting this error when I compile a sketch using that library.

Comment: Which line does to the compiler indicate? You have added some extra character or added extern also in the implementation.

Comment: It is pointing at:      extern num_func functions[];

And I've NOT added extern in the implementation.

Comment: What compiler/IDE version are you using? You have not answered the question about the setup. You must provide more information.

Comment: I'm using Arduino IDE latest uptodate.

And I can provide more information of course. What do you mean by "What is your setup?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36245/discussion-between-faraz-ahmad-and-mikael-patel).

Comment: Ah, one thing that might be of worth noting is I've declared the functions zero() etc. as members of the class.

Comment: I've tried the implementation of the function as you've in your edited answer, but as a member of the class I'm talking about. And my implementation in the loop() is as follow:     myClassNamet::functions[1]();

Now I'm getting additional error "invalid use of non-static data member 'myClassName::functions'

Comment: I have migrated your answer to be comments under your question. You can always edit the question itself and add additional notes in response to answers.

Comment: You must define the member function as static. But then it cannot access member data as there is no this reference. Please mark this question as answered or at least update your original question with with is not yet answered.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bit fiddly to get right. I got inspiration from [How do I create and use an array of pointer-to-member-function?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#array-memfnptrs)

Based on my [post about Function pointers / function callbacks / function variables](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12607) I modified it to work with class functions:

```
class foo {

  public:

   void doAction0 ()
    {
      Serial.println (0);
    }

    void doAction1 ()
    {
      Serial.println (1);
    }

    void doAction2 ()
    {
      Serial.println (2);
    }

    void doAction3 ()
    {
      Serial.println (3);
    }

    void doAction4 ()
    {
      Serial.println (4);
    }

   // typedef for class function
   typedef void (foo::*GeneralFunction) ();

   // array of function pointers
    GeneralFunction doActionsArray [5] =
    {
      &foo::doAction0, 
      &foo::doAction1, 
      &foo::doAction2, 
      &foo::doAction3, 
      &foo::doAction4, 
    };

};  // end of class foo

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();
  Serial.println (F("Starting"));

  // test instance of foo
  foo bar;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    // get member function pointer from array
    foo::GeneralFunction f = bar.foo::doActionsArray [i];
    // call the function
    (bar.*f) ();
    }  // end of for loop

}  // end of setup

void loop () { }
```

This compiles OK and prints:

```
Starting
0
1
2
3
4
```

---

### Amended answer

I was wondering why you needed to specify `bar` in this line above:

```
    foo::GeneralFunction f = bar.foo::doActionsArray [i];
```

The reason is that the code above had the array as non-static, and thus a copy belonged to each instance of the class. This doesn't make a huge amount of sense, so the modified code below makes the array `static` and `const`. That is, the array should be the same for every instance of `foo` and also never change.

Modified code below:

```
class foo {

  public:

   void doAction0 ()
    {
      Serial.println (0);
    }

    void doAction1 ()
    {
      Serial.println (1);
    }

    void doAction2 ()
    {
      Serial.println (2);
    }

    void doAction3 ()
    {
      Serial.println (3);
    }

    void doAction4 ()
    {
      Serial.println (4);
    }

   // typedef for class function
   typedef void (foo::*GeneralFunction) ();

   static const GeneralFunction doActionsArray [5];

};  // end of class foo

 // array of function pointers
const foo::GeneralFunction foo::doActionsArray [5] =
  {
    &foo::doAction0, 
    &foo::doAction1, 
    &foo::doAction2, 
    &foo::doAction3, 
    &foo::doAction4, 
  };

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();
  Serial.println (F("Starting"));

  // test instance of foo
  foo bar;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    // get member function pointer from array
    foo::GeneralFunction f = foo::doActionsArray [i];
    // call the function
    (bar.*f) ();
    }

}  // end of setup

void loop () { }
```

This will also save RAM, as the array of function pointers only exists once, not once per instance of the class.

Comment: See amended answer. The second method is a bit simpler and uses less RAM.

Answer (score 1):

First you need a header file - let's say lib.h:

```
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H

typedef void (*num_func) ();
extern num_func functions[];

#endif
```

And then the implementation, lib.cpp:

```
#include "lib.h"

void zero();
void one();
void two();
void three();
void four();
void five();
void six();
void seven();
void eight();
void nine();

num_func functions[] = { zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine};
```

The functions could be declared as static (if you want to hide them) and they do need implementation. They are only forward declarations above. Below is a snippet of a sketch using the library (assuming that it is within the sketch folder).

```
#include "lib.h"

void setup()
{
  ...
}
void loop()
{
  ...
  // Call to the one() function
  functions[1]();
  ...
}
```

Cheers!